# Monty Hall Problem Trouble

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, monty-hall

This problem is from Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein and Hwang (Chapter 2, exercise 40)

> The ratings of Monty Hall's show have dropped slightly, and a panicking executive producer complains to Monty that the part of the show where he opens a door lacks suspense: Monty always opens a door with a goat. Monty replies that the reason is so that the game is never spoiled by him revealing the car, but he agrees to update the game as follows.
> Before each show, Monty secretly flips a coin with probability *p* of heads. If the coin lands Heads, Monty resolves to open a goat door (with equal probabilities if there is a choice). Otherwise, Monty resolves to open a random unopened door, with equal probabilities. The contestant knows *p* but does not know the outcome of the coin flip. When the show starts, the contestant chooses a door. Monty (who knows where the car is) then opens a door. If the car is revealed, the game is over; if a goat is revealed, the contestant is offered the option of switching. Now suppose it turns out that the contestant chooses door 1 and then Monty opens door 2, revealing a goat. What is the contestant's probability of success if he or she switches to door 3?

The issue is, almost every place I've seen this problem solved states:

1. Flipping the coin is independent of position of the car or the choice of door that Monty opens
2. Car’s position is independent from coin’s toss or Monty’s door opening

My intuition feels like there are errors within these assumptions and I would like somebody to check my work and tell me what (if any) that I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

My work:

$W$ = Event that you win

$G_i$ = Goat behind the $i^{th}$ door

$M_i$ = Monty opened the $i^{th}$ door

$H$ = Heads

$T$ = Tails

$P(W|G_2,M_2)=P(W|G_2,M_2,H)*P(H|G_2,M_2)+P(W|G_2,M_2,T)*P(T|G_2,M_2)$

$P(W|G_2,M_2,H) = P(W|G_2,M_2,H,C_3)*P(C_3|G_2,M_2,H)$

$P(C_3|G_2,M_2,H) = \frac{P(G_2,M_2|C_3,H)*P(C_3|H)}{P(G_2,M_2|H)}= \frac{1*\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}}= \frac{2}{3}$

$P(H|G_2,M_2) = \frac{P(G_2,M_2|H)*P(H)}{P(G_2,M_2)}=\frac{P(G_2,M_2|H)*P(H)}{P(G_2,M_2|H)*P(H)+P(G_2,M_2|T)*P(T)}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}*p}{\frac{1}{2}*p + \frac{1}{3}*(1-p)}$

$P(W|G_2,M_2,T) = P(W|G_2,M_2,T,C_3)*P(C_3|G_2,M_2,T)$

$P(C_3|G_2,M_2,T) = \frac{P(G_2,M_2|C_3,T)*P(C_3|T)}{P(G_2,M_2|T)}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}}= \frac{1}{2}$

$P(T|G_2,M_2) = \frac{P(G_2,M_2|T)*P(T)}{P(G_2,M_2)}=\frac{P(G_2,M_2|T)*P(T)}{P(G_2,M_2|H)*P(H)+P(G_2,M_2|T)*P(T)}= \frac{\frac{1}{3}*(1-p)}{\frac{1}{2}*p + \frac{1}{3}*(1-p)}$

Comment: The first assumptions seems solid..surely the placement of the car has no effect on the coin toss.  But I don't think they mean the second one as stated.  Obviously the location of the car has an effect on the door Monty chooses.

Comment: The contestant should still switch. If Monty chooses randomly, with a chance of ruining the game, then switching or staying has the same chance of winning. But if Monty only reveals the goat then we are back to a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of winning if we switch. The probability of winning would then be $$\frac{2}{3}p+(1-p)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}p$$

Comment: I'm not sure what part of your calculation was meant to be an answer but you should be able to check your result by looking at the two extremes.  If $p=1$ then this is the ordinary Monty Hall problem, so switching should win with probability $\frac 23$.  If $p=0$ then Monty is guessing blindly, so switching offers no advantage, and should therefore win with probability $\frac 12$.

Comment: Like I figured that I'm conceptually wrong somewhere and was wondering where I was making a mistake. Thank you for your suggestions, looking at extreme cases makes a lot of sense

Comment: Small suggestion as I read this: I think you shouldn't use $W$ -- you should use $C_1$ and $C_3$.